# HtmlDriver with Javascript Exception

Tags: javascript, selenium, htmlunit

I have this code:

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        ((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);

        baseUrl = "http://www.url.com/";

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
            ...
```

But if i try to Run i have this exception:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "match" of undefined (http://www.url.com//javascript/jquery.ceebox/jquery.swfobject.js#2)
```

How i can solve it? there is a way?

Comment: Just check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315330/how-to-overcame-htmlunit-scriptexception)

Comment: but i can't use a driver?

Comment: As I explained in the answer, it is only a matter of not being able to execute the JS. Read the answer again

Comment: i read and i haven't control over the source code from server.. and i won't to show up the Browser, so i use the HtmlUnitDriver..there is a solution for me?..if i use WebClient i must write all code, but i want to use selenium for that.

Comment: There isn't much to do apart from what it says there. You want to use a tool that is not letting you go anywhere. Solution: Do not use the tool.

Comment: but i can use WebClient and not show a browser windows?..

Answer (score 0):

The javascript support is not upto the mark and if you just wan't to suppress these errors, you can use :

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

My generic webclient configuration looks like below, in almost all of my projects :

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        client.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

Comment: but in this case, Browser Firefox start or not?..because i don't want this

Comment: `htmlunit` is a headless browser, Firefox is just to set as default user-agent, it won't fire/start Firefox.

Comment: i use htmlunit but i have this error...i have   driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

Comment: above code corresponds to `selenium` and my solution corresponds to pure `htmlunit`

Comment: but in selenium if i try to export code in Java i have a driver not a webclient

Comment: @FelasDroid the question is about using `htmlunit` driver in `selenium` and I've written the answer using `pure htmlunit`