# Selenium WebDriver Java RunTimeException thrown when trying to get the url's content

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to get the content from the url after all tables are loaded. The code works perfectly for other urls which also load the tables with ajax, but I assume that this has some javascript exception that has not been handled and I am not sure if WebDriver can ignore it. What am I missing? Thank you for your help. Here is my code

```
    URL url;
    String content;

    try {
        url = new URL(
                "http://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/spot-market/auction");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);

    driver.get(url.toString());

    WebElement e = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
            .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("table.table-horizontal")));
    List<WebElement> rows = e.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    for (WebElement row : rows) {
        List<WebElement> columns = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (WebElement column : columns) {
            result.append(column.getText() + "\t");
            System.out.print(column.getText() + "\t");
        }
        result.append("\n");
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

And this is the Exception that I get

```
Sep 15, 2014 2:28:18 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl runSingleJob
SEVERE: Job run failed with unexpected RuntimeException: TypeError: Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all. (http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js#6)
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[6] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all. (http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js#6)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all. (http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js#6)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:705)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:637)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.setState(XMLHttpRequest.java:223)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.doSend(XMLHttpRequest.java:731)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.access$000(XMLHttpRequest.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest$1.run(XMLHttpRequest.java:611)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavascriptXMLHttpRequestJob.run(JavascriptXMLHttpRequestJob.java:36)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:328)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all. (http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js#6)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3629)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3613)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError3(ScriptRuntime.java:3656)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.SimpleScriptable.isReadOnlySettable(SimpleScriptable.java:462)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$GetterSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:259)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putImpl(ScriptableObject.java:2796)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2479)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1574)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1569)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1253)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3057)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:630)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:690)
    ... 13 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot set property [HTMLStyleElement].media that has only a getter to all. (http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js#6)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3629)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3613)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError3(ScriptRuntime.java:3656)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.SimpleScriptable.isReadOnlySettable(SimpleScriptable.java:462)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$GetterSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:259)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putImpl(ScriptableObject.java:2796)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2479)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1574)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1569)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1253)
    at script(http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js:6)
    at script(http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js:5)
    at script(http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js:3)
    at script(http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-compatibility.js:7)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3057)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:630)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:690)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:637)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.setState(XMLHttpRequest.java:223)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.doSend(XMLHttpRequest.java:731)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest.access$000(XMLHttpRequest.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.xml.XMLHttpRequest$1.run(XMLHttpRequest.java:611)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavascriptXMLHttpRequestJob.run(JavascriptXMLHttpRequestJob.java:36)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:328)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==

  function () {
      4 !== c.readyState || 200 !== c.status && 304 !== c.status || b(c.responseText);
  }

======= EXCEPTION END ========

Sep 15, 2014 2:28:19 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Sep 15, 2014 2:28:19 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Sep 15, 2014 2:28:21 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Sep 15, 2014 2:28:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: ':checked' error: Invalid selector: *:checked).] sourceName=[http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-vendor.js] line=[1] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Sep 15, 2014 2:28:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: ':enabled' error: Invalid selector: *:enabled).] sourceName=[http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-vendor.js] line=[1] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Sep 15, 2014 2:28:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-vendor.js] line=[1] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "Element" is not defined. (http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-vendor.js#1)
Build info: version: '2.43.0', revision: '597b76b', time: '2014-09-09 20:52:38'
System info: host: 'Marija-PC', ip: '169.254.80.80', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:489)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:465)
    at mk.eds.aggregator.services.impl.EexAggregatorService.getContentFromUrl(EexAggregatorService.java:50)
    at mk.eds.aggregator.TestService.main(TestService.java:119)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "Element" is not defined. (http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-vendor.js#1)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:705)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:591)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1078)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:393)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:288)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:741)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:701)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:965)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:247)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:193)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:468)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:342)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:476)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Element" is not defined. (http://www.eex.com/blueprint/assets/js/prototype-vendor.js#1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3629)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3613)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3683)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1690)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1622)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3057)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:582)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:690)
    ... 32 more
Sep 15, 2014 2:28:22 PM TestService main
```

Comment: Are you required to use HtmlUnitDriver? Does it behave same when using FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver, or other "real" browser?

Comment: Yes, I have to use HtmlUnitDriver. I can't use Firefox or Chrome Driver.

Comment: maybe the answer from this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315330/how-to-overcame-htmlunit-scriptexception

Comment: Not really helpful because it is about WebClient and other Drivers, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Consider the link above as it contains a possible way, even not the nicest but have to use it sometimes too. Hint WebClient is HTMLUnit specific and you can extend the HTMLUnit driver and override modifyWebClient() to set this option

Comment: Are you able to use
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);

Comment: I've found HtmlUnity to be fussy about javascript, and not representative of how real-life browsers behave. For headless testing, I've had a lot more success using PhantomJS instead with GhostDriver - is that something you could change to?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try directly giving the url and check?

```
driver.get("http://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/spot-market/auction");
```