# htmlunit always gives multiple javascript exceptions after running the project

Tags: java, webclient, java-7, htmlunit, swingx

I'm working on a project that checks an email list that is imported to see if the user is registered or not on yahoo.

When I click on the Start button, it should go to the yahoo mail sign up page and check every email on this imported txt file. I've relied on htmlunit library but it always gives an exception, despite disabling the JavaScript and ThrowExceptionOnScriptError

**this the exceptions always happens**

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[110] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js] message=[TypeError: Method "toString" called on incompatible object. (https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js#110)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Method "toString" called on incompatible object. (https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js#110)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:898)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:778)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:754)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:980)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:781)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:738)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1243)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1143)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3154)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2117)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:988)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:520)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:459)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:444)
    at ec.Checker.yahooChecker(Checker.java:36)
    at ec.ProgramFrame.startActionPerformed(ProgramFrame.java:214)
    at ec.ProgramFrame.access$100(ProgramFrame.java:26)
    at ec.ProgramFrame$2.actionPerformed(ProgramFrame.java:105)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Method "toString" called on incompatible object. (https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js#110)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError1(ScriptRuntime.java:3934)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.BaseFunction.realFunction(BaseFunction.java:354)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:299)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:94)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.FunctionWrapper.call(FunctionWrapper.java:43)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.NativeFunctionToStringFunction$NativeFunctionToStringFunctionChrome.call(NativeFunctionToStringFunction.java:88)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2575)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:321)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:94)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:416)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:292)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:769)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:883)
    ... 71 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Method "toString" called on incompatible object. (https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js#110)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError1(ScriptRuntime.java:3934)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.BaseFunction.realFunction(BaseFunction.java:354)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:299)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:94)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.FunctionWrapper.call(FunctionWrapper.java:43)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.NativeFunctionToStringFunction$NativeFunctionToStringFunctionChrome.call(NativeFunctionToStringFunction.java:88)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2575)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:321)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:94)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
    at script(https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js:110)
    at script(https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js:110)
    at script(https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js:111)
    at script.trackSection(https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js:84)
    at script(https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js:84)
    at script.s(https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js:1)
    at script.e(https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js:1)
    at script(https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?wm/mbr/0.1.4453/bundle.js:1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:416)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:292)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:769)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:883)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:778)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:754)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:980)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:781)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:738)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1243)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1143)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3154)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2117)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:988)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:520)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:459)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:444)
    at ec.Checker.yahooChecker(Checker.java:36)
    at ec.ProgramFrame.startActionPerformed(ProgramFrame.java:214)
    at ec.ProgramFrame.access$100(ProgramFrame.java:26)
    at ec.ProgramFrame$2.actionPerformed(ProgramFrame.java:105)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

**the Checker class**

```
    package ec;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Checker {
public void yahooChecker() {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(ProgramFrame.emailsFile.getPath())))) {
        String email = br.readLine();
        while ((email = br.readLine()) != null) {
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://login.yahoo.com/account/create?specId=yidReg&lang=en-JO&src=ym&done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&display=login&intl=xa");

            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

            final DomElement firstName = page1.getElementById("firstName");
            final HtmlSubmitInput emailAddress = page1.getElementByName("yid");
            final DomElement takenMsg = page1.getElementById("usernamereg-altreg");

            emailAddress.setTextContent(email);
            firstName.click();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(650);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Checker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if (takenMsg.isDisplayed()) {
                String takenEmails = emailAddress.getTextContent();
                ProgramFrame.takenEmails.append(takenEmails + "\n");


            } else {
                String availableEmails = emailAddress.getTextContent();
                ProgramFrame.availableEmails.append(availableEmails + "\n");


            }

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Checker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
}
```

**the GUI of the program**

[image: Emails Checker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setJavaScriptEnabled(false)` should be called *before* getting the page, otherwise the JavaScript will be executed.

So, your code should be:

```
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://login.yahoo.com/account/create?specId=yidReg&lang=en-JO&src=ym&done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&display=login&intl=xa");
```

Comment: thanks, it's worked finally , but I use System.out.println(takenEmails + "\n");
to output the emails, Did you know Why didn't output on JXTextArea ?

Comment: Could be because of EndOfLine (e.g. `\r\n` , `\r` or `\n`), you can iterate over all characters of the string to investigate it further.

Comment: \n to enter new line after every checking for email, it's working but it output the result when the end of read and check all emails from the txt file, the problem now is locate elemnt reg-error-yid in yahoo sing up page, to relate see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925657/how-to-locate-element-with-tag-alert-inside-outer-div/43931545#43931545) if you can help

Answer (score 1):

This is why HtmlUnit is not so frequently used when working with Js heavy web pages. In short, it utilizes it's own JS engine that often doesn't process JS as other real browsers do. You may read full explanation here: [How to overcome an HTMLUnit ScriptException?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20315631/1967021)

I'd recommend using a `WebDriver` for this instead.

Comment: thanks , but Have you read will What the program doing exactly? , I was trying before using selenium.webdriver "Chrome driver" it's opened multiple browser windows for every email check process ! , so that I used htmlunit inested of Webdriver

Comment: You have full controll of those windows - just switch between them, do the work and call `driver.close()` on the window you don't need