# How to locate element with tag alert inside outer div

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, webclient, htmlunit

I trying to locate elemnts in [this page](https://login.yahoo.com/account/create?specId=yidReg&lang=en-JO&src=ym&done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&display=login&intl=xa) and put it in Objects (DomElement) to making some tests of it, the problem is with elemnt reg-error-yid it is a inner-div inside div yid-field-suggestion, I tried to getElementById, byName, byXPath, and getFirstByXPath it's all not working , also I tried to change webClient with WebDriver and use `driver.findElement(By.className("oneid-error-message"))` it's also not working

**the elemnt of registered message**

```
<div id="reg-error-yid" class="oneid-error-message" data-error="messages.IDENTIFIER_EXISTS" role="alert">A Yahoo account already exists with this email address. <a href="https://login.yahoo.com/?intl=xa&amp;lang=en-JO&amp;src=ym&amp;.intl=xa&amp;specId=yidReg&amp;.done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&amp;nr=1&amp;step=2&amp;.crumb=qP.UnkGzfkR&amp;login=abtallaldigital">Sign in</a>.</div>
```

**my code**

```
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://login.yahoo.com/account/create?specId=yidReg&lang=en-JO&src=ym&done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&display=login&intl=xa");

             final DomElement firstName = page1.getElementById("usernamereg-firstName");
             final DomElement emailAddress = page1.getElementById("usernamereg-yid");
             final DomElement takenMsg = page1.getElementById("reg-error-yid");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your need. I can't comment here.

But if you are trying to parse the document you can use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download) for parsing the document.

The `select` is more useful and easy as compared to `getElementById, byName, byXPath`.

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://login.yahoo.com/account/create?specId=yidReg&lang=en-JO&src=ym&done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&display=login&intl=xa").get();
org.jsoup.select.Elements takenMsgs = doc.select("div[id=reg-error-yid]");
org.jsoup.select.Element takenMsgFirst = doc.select("div[id=reg-error-yid]").first;
```

See if you can convert `org.jsoup.select.Elements` to `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement`

Comment: thank you, see this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901997/htmlunit-always-gives-multiple-javascript-exceptions-after-running-the-project) to be related